# hapi.js Cors Pre-flight not returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, dropzone.js, hapi.js

I have an ajax file upload using (Dropzone js). which sends a file to my hapi server. I realised the browser sends a PREFLIGHT OPTIONS METHOD. but my hapi server seems not to send the right response headers so i am getting errors on chrome.
here is the error i get on chrome

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/uploadbookimg. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

this is the hapi js route handler

```
server.route({
        path: '/uploadbookimg',
        method: 'POST',
        config: {
            cors : true,
            payload: {
                output: 'stream',
                parse: true,
                allow: 'multipart/form-data'
            },
        handler: require('./books/webbookimgupload'),
        }
    });
```

In my understanding hapi js should send all cors headers from the Pre-fight (OPTIONS) request.
Cant understand why its is not

Network request /response from chrome

```
**General**
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000

**Response Headers**
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: no-cache
vary: accept-encoding
Date: Wed, 27 Apr 2016 07:25:33 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

**Request Headers**
view parsed
OPTIONS /uploadbookimg HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, cache-control, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/books/upload
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Hapi Cors Header Plugin [https://github.com/gr2m/hapi-cors-headers](https://github.com/gr2m/hapi-cors-headers).

Answer (score 22):

The hapi `cors: true` is a wildcard rule that allows CORS requests from all domains except for a few cases including when there are additional request headers outside of [hapi's default whitelist](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L87-L92):

`["accept", "authorization", "content-type", "if-none-match", "origin"]`

[See the `cors` option section in the API docs under route options](https://web.archive.org/web/20170709183526/https://hapijs.com/api#route-options):

> `headers` - a strings array of allowed headers ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers'). Defaults to `['Accept', 'Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'If-None-Match']`.
>
> `additionalHeaders` - a strings array of additional headers to `headers`. Use this to keep the default headers in place.

Your problem is that Dropzone sends a couple of headers along with the file upload that aren't in this list:

- `x-requested-with` (not in your headers above but was sent for me)
- `cache-control`

You have two options to get things working, you need to change something on either the server or the client:

### Option 1 - Whitelist the extra headers:

```
server.route({
    config: {
        cors: {
            origin: ['*'],
            additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with']
        }
    },
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/upload',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        ...
    }
});
```

### Option 2 - Tell dropzone to not send those extra headers

Not possible yet through their config but there's a pending PR to allow it: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/pull/685

Comment: ok..this worked perfectly, one other solution i found out was was to use the hapi-cors-header plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-cors-headers

Comment: Yes that would work. Wouldn't recommend it though. The strict whitelist is there for a reason (security).

Comment: Is there a method of setting the CORS origin for all routes rather than on a route-by-route basis?

Comment: @Notamachine  Yes it is possible, you can do it by adding it to the server configs, instead of the route config.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add my 2 cents on this one as the above did not fully resolve the issue in my case.

I started my Hapi-Server at `localhost:3300`. Then I made a request from `localhost:80` to `http://localhost:3300/` to test CORS. This lead to chrome still blocking the ressource because it said that

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

(which was not true at all). 
**Then** I changed the XHR-Request to fetch the url to a url for which I actually created a route inside HapiJS which - in my case - was `http://localhost:3300/api/test`. **This worked**.

To overgo this issue I created a "catch-all" route in HapiJS (to overgo the built-in 404 catch).

```
const Boom = require('Boom'); //You can require Boom when you have hapi

Route({
  method: '*',
  path: '/{any*}',
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    reply(Boom.notFound());
  }
})
```