# Nodejs Hapi - How to enable cross origin access control

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am working HapiJs Restful web service and trying to enable cors so any client even from different domain can consume my services. I tried cors=true in server connection object but didn't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Where did you put `cors=true`? Could you add some code?

Without know exactly where you've put `cors = true`, this bit of code may help you:

```
server.connection({ routes: { cors: true } })
```

Or try adding the allowed cors in the config section of your route.

```
server.route({
    config: {
        cors: {
            origin: ['*'],
            additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with']
        }
    },
```

Take a look at this question: [hapi.js Cors Pre-flight not returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883860/hapi-js-cors-pre-flight-not-returning-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: // Create a server with a host and port
var server = new Hapi.Server();

//server connection settings
server.connection({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
    
    routes: {
        cors:true,
        files: {
            
            relativeTo: path.resolve('.', 'build')
        }
    }

});

Comment: The `cors:true`was all it needed. Thanks! Here's the complete connection config: `server.connection({ port: +process.env.PORT || 5000, host: '0.0.0.0', routes: { cors: true } });`

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @[James111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904791/2219158)'s answer,

Even if that answer doesn't work for you. check for additional Auth headers that you are sending.

In my case it was `X_AUTH_TOKEN`, so in `additionalHeaders` you might want to add your custom header as well.

e.g.

```
additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with', 'X_AUTH_TOKEN']
```