# axios autohorization headers / CORS error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, react-native, axios

I'm using react with axios to fetch some information. I'm sending JWT token to auth user and im geting response in console browser

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://beer-tonight.herokuapp.com/beer/getBeerStatus' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

This is my code:

```
componentWillMount(){

    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');


    axios.get('https://beer-tonight.herokuapp.com/beer/getBeerStatus', {headers: {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token}}).then(
    result => {
        console.log('yey');
    });
}
```

Error:

[image]

When I am using POSTMAN I am getting proper answer.

Postman input:

[image]

p.s. i already added :

```
app.use((req, res,next)=>{
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorisation');
next();
```

Comment: you are using `chrome`, right?

Comment: Yes, i am using chrome

Comment: There is a minor typo 'Authorisation' should be as you have it in your header key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've written `Authorisation`:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorisation');
```

But the header is `Authorization` as you have used with axios, try changing that and seeing if it works then,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cors error that you are receiving is from your node.js api. (https://beer-tonight.herokuapp.com/beer/getBeerStatus)

Since the host do are not the same origin (`beer-tonight.herokuapp.com` does not match with `localhost`), you need to enable cors for your node.js server.

If you are using express:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// ...
```

**Source:** [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Hapi.js:

```
server.connection({ routes: { cors: true } })
```

**Source:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904597/nodejs-hapi-how-to-enable-cross-origin-access-control)

Once you have CORS enabled, everything should work smoothly. [More on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)