# Hapi.js v17 CORS Pre-flight not returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, hapi.js

I developed REST WebServices using NodeJs + HapiJs V17, I integrated with Angular 6, when I start hitting the POST/PUT requests am facing trouble with CORS
I Deployed the HapiJS application in localhost and port 4000, running the Angular 6 code using Angular Cli.

When I executed this from Chrome browser I am getting the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/authenticateUser' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried various options in the headers section of Hapi Server

Hapi Server Code

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({
  port: 4000, routes: {
    cors: {
      origin: ['*'],
      headers: ["Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "If-None-Match", "Accept-language"]
    }
  }
});
```

Angular 6

```
public login(payload: TokenPayload): Observable<ServiceResponse> {
        return this.http.post<ServiceResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/authenticateUser`, payload)
            .pipe(map(response => {
                if (response.data) this.saveUser(response.data);
                return response;
            }));
    }
```

I searched over many posts and tried many things but no luck. 
If anyone faced this issue and resolved it, please post me a solution.
This is blocking my production release.

This is not a duplicate post of the below link: 
[hapi.js Cors Pre-flight not returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883860/hapi-js-cors-pre-flight-not-returning-access-control-allow-origin-header)

In the above link, it was the issue from Hapi V16.
But I am facing the issue in HapiJS V17.

---

I found the solution:

use hapi-cors plugin, see the below sample code.

```
await server.register({
 plugin: require('hapi-cors'),
 options: {
   origins: ['*'],
   allowCredentials: 'true',
   exposeHeaders: ['content-type', 'content-length'],
   maxAge: 600,
   methods: ['GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'],
   headers: ['Accept', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization'] // add your header params
 },
 checkOrigin: true
});

await server.start();`
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK?

Comment: It is Status Code: 200 OK